# Kotlin: null and "Overload resolution ambiguity"

Tags: kotlin, null, overloading

I want to call a overloaded java-function from Kotlin. I want to use a `null` for parameter that significant to a overload resolution.

How to specify `IntArray` type for `null` value?

I don't like a solution with additional varibale of common type.

[image]

Comment: It seems as if the compiler has been improved regarding this constellation... with kotlin 1.3.72 having a variable initialized to `null` but with appropriate type, now calls the correct function without issues...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of a variable just cast it, i.e. `null as IntArray?`, e.g.:

```
origImg.data.getSamples(0, 0, origImg.width, origImg.height, 0, null as IntArray?)
```

Note that this is the same behaviour as in Java, where you also needed to cast `null`, e.g. `(int[]) null`, to call the appropriate overloaded method.

You could build a function that gives you a ~typed `null` (if it doesn't exist yet) with a reified type:

```
inline fun <reified T>typedNull(): T? = null
```

and calling it with:

```
typedNull<IntArray>()
```

But then again, `null as IntArray?` is clear enough I think and people know it already.

Comment: Good point in underlying the "no difference" behavior compared to plain Java

Comment: I've tried `null as IntArray` and got `null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.IntArray`. Yes, `?` is significant. Thanks.

Comment: Ah... well, yes... Only types with a `?` can hold `null` values, others not.